# Sync winrt sqlite with online mysql db

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, winrt-xaml

I am working on win8 app using sqlite as offline db. I also have a website with same functionality. So user can use offline winrt app and website.
Now I want a way to sync two db. Is there any algorithm or a technique? I have very short span of time and its really gonna tough task.

Comment: [SYNCHRONIZING WINRT/SQLITE USING SYNC FRAMEWORK TOOLKIT](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/synchronizing-winrtsqlite-using-sync-framework-toolkit/)

Comment: Is that workd for Mysql also?

Answer (score 0):

As Xyroid already suggested, given the short time frame, your best bet is to use [Sync Toolkit Windows 8 WinRT](https://syncwinrt.codeplex.com/). It's built on top of [Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e), adding support for Windows 8 clients to it. The only prerequisite is that you're using SQLite as the database on the client, which you are.

These two frameworks both use [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx) on the back end which should support any database that can be accessed using ADO.NET. Assuming that you're using an appropriate ADO.NET provider for MySQL to access the database it should work just fine.

It'll still be some work to make the synchronization work but definitely a lot less than if you'd be doing it all from scratch. Take into account, though, that you might need to modify the databse structure a bit to make the synchonization work.